# Why is there download of data automatically

Tags: appcenter

I see that there is 3.2 mb of data that gets downloaded every time I sign into the Internet wifi.  Can I prevent this and what is it?

I suspect it is the update from the app store because I have often tried to install upon booting, and I get an apt lock problem.  after a few minutes, no apt lock problems and sometimes I get a message that updates are available (without `doing sudo apt update`)
Can I disable this "feature"?

[image]

Comment: First, use `nethogs` to check what is really using that 3,2 MiB.  elementary OS  only checks for updates once a day (when you boot). Not every time you connect to a wifi network.

Comment: usually the apt lock file is locked until 3.2 is used.  Then I can use apt.  I will check a few times.  I also do not like the idea that it does an update without my wanting.  Once a day or not.  (I think it is more, since I have been online several times per day.)

Comment: First check that. If the issue is apt then follow this guide to disable it: https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/18/ubuntu-16-04-auto-apt-update-and-apt-upgrade/#sec-7  but remember that you'll have to update and upgrade manually.

Comment: ok.. thanks.. I have the GUI installed and unchecked it.

Comment: /usr/lib/apt/methods/http has several processes.  I have already removed daily checks from the UI software updates applet.  But I did not do the command line thing to shut down the timer and update.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify earlier. You just need to do step 7. That will stop apt from updating at boot.

Comment: Still have usr/lib/apt/methods/http grabbing 3mb

Comment: Check if you disabled both of them correctly: `systemctl status apt-daily.service` and `systemctl status apt-daily.timer`. If that's correct, now do this: `sudo scratch-text-editor  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` and set `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0"`. I haven't tried it but it may work.

Comment: I ran the commands a couple of days ago, but they still show as enabled.  So I ran the code again and then ran your "check" and it is still enabled.  http://pastebin.com/BNgUpzfc

Comment: Well then you are doing something incorrectly... did you `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after disabling both apt entries?

Comment: Not sure if this did it.  I had done the above pastebin prior to a  new reboot.  So reload would not matter, unless, the config file need editing.  which I will do and report back.. In the mean time here is the pastebin for your commands. http://pastebin.com/GrEZFPPd   Update:   I edited it (after pastebin report.) it is already zero, but I set unattended updates to 0, whatever that is.  (It was set to 1... everything else was zero)

Comment: It still does the downloading like before.  Even with everything in the file you told me about set to "0"

Comment: At this point i'm out of ideas... Maybe you can try the first answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315502/how-to-disable-apt-daily-service-on-ubuntu-cloud-vm-image/315535 but I don't know where or how you apply that script at boot. Anyway, I recommend you to ask this question in a bigger forum (like askUbuntu or something) because your issue may also happen on other Ubuntu distros and you are more likely to find an answer there. Good luck :)

Comment: I am just curious.. is it just me  who has this problem or I am the only one who cares about this.?

Comment: The second probably.

Comment: Can you verify this .  I have compiled and installed (and then removed) purple-facebook.  This was suspicious because it downloaded lots of binaries (many and large in size).  The whole point of compiling is that it is code you can see.  I posted this on ubuntu gplus but nobody cared either.  You cannot post eOS questions on askUbuntu.  They flag you.

Comment: Hmm if you just say that apt downloads 3mb of data every time you connect to WiFi you would be fine. If they ask, your OS is Ubuntu 14.04 .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing a fresh install and deleting the Elementary appcenter

`sudo apt remove appcenter`.

Finished and I never use it anyway.

I am sure this hurts the devs, and I hope they fix it with future releases.  Basically, if I say I don't want to check for updates.. that means don't check for updates.  (hint).